# Jenkins' Job DSL throws ConcurrentModificationException when I define a BooleanParameterDefinition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to add a boolean parameter to an existing Jenkins job, but when I add it my seedjob stops working.

My job definition:

```
job('ci') {
    description 'Build and test the app.'
    scm {
        github 'sheehan/job-dsl-playground'
    }
    steps {
        gradle 'test'
    }
    publishers {
        archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
    configure { project ->
        project / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' {
            'parameterDefinitions'  {
                'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition' {
                    name('my-param')
                    description("my-param-description")
                    defaultValue(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can reproduce the error by pasting the job definition code in this page: https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is still there, but I managed to work around it by removing the `BooleanParameterDefinition`'s description. So my final code looks like this:

```
job('ci') {
    description 'Build and test the app.'
    scm {
        github 'sheehan/job-dsl-playground'
    }
    steps {
        gradle 'test'
    }
    publishers {
        archiveJunit 'build/test-results/**/*.xml'
    }
    configure { project ->
        project / 'properties' / 'hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty' {
            'parameterDefinitions'  {
                'hudson.model.BooleanParameterDefinition' {
                    name('my-param')
                    defaultValue(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```